# Logging out using Url.Action or a post form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got an ASP.NET MVC website I am working on. I am puzzled between using two different ways of logging out.

One way I saw that works for me is

```
<li>
    <form method="post" asp-action="logout" asp-controller="Account">
        <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log Out</a>
    </form>
</li>
```

Versus just using a Url.Action

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("logout", "Account")" class="elements"><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log Out</a></li>
```

Both ways behave the way I want them. The only difference is I prefer using @Url.Action because I am able to style it better. Is this just preference or is there a standard on doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost same way. But with `@Url.Action` you can have more `overloading` like add more `parameter` (route values) if need.

Refer more overloading  `@Url.Action` at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: I made an edit because I noticed a mistake. But I think you understood what I mean. I forgot to add the actual Url.Action in the original post. But I agree, I like Url.Action more just wasn't sure if there was a correct or standard way of doing it. Thanks